# I have the following date: 2010-04-19

Tags: php, string, laravel, date

I have the following date: 2010-04-19 .

I would like to convert this date strtotime format and convert "Y-m" format.

Example = "2018-5"

my code:

```
$date1= 'onlinearticles_'.$date;
$article_table= date('Y-m',strtotime($date1));
```

But it didin't work, how can I do this ?

Comment: What is your Question ?

Comment: I have the following date: 2018-5-3 . I would like to convert this date strtotime format and i went this output 'onlinearticles_ 2018-5'

Comment: What output did you except ?

Comment: 'onlinearticles_ 2018-5

Comment: Sorry. What did you get instead ? I don't really get the issue.

Comment: i need  as like as 'onlinearticles_ 2018-5 this type of output

Comment: I still don't really get the point but the function strtotime() expects a valid(!) date/time string https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php I think ````'onlinearticles_'.$date```` isn't one

Answer (score 1):

you should add alphabetic characters later..

follow these steps;

```
$date = 2010-04-19;

$newDate = date("Y-m",strtotime($date));

$stringWithDate = "onlinearticles_".$newDate;

dd($stringWithDate);
```